# in laravel 8 for API controller , how show the ID not found message as json?

Tags: json, laravel, api

i'm working with laravel 8 and building an API.

I have a CategoryController and doing CRUD. in my  store method ,  When i enter an ID that does not exist , i want to show a message that says : `category not found`

and i don't know how to put it in the method.

this is my categorycontroller and my update method :

```
public function update(Request $request, Category $category)
    {
        $data = $request->all();

        $validator = Validator::make($data, [
            'title' => 'required|max:100|unique:categories',
            'description' => 'required|max:500',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response(['error' => $validator->errors(), 'Validation Error']);
        }

        $category->title = $data['title'];
        $category->description = $data['description'];
        $category->save();

        return response()->json([
        "success" => true,
        "message" => "با موفقیت ویرایش گردید",
        "data" => $category
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: What is your appropriate route for update ?

Comment: in postman i enter this route : `http://localhost:8000/api/subcategories/100?parent_id=104&title=examplr&description=example`

Comment: and in my api.php i have resource : `Route::apiResource('categories' , CategoryController::class);
`

Comment: I wanted to know about category field. Anyway if it's "category_id" (the field name in the POST/PUT request (actually in REST apps you need to run PUT request in the postman for updates)), then you can replace "Category $category" to "int $category_id" in your method's 2-nd argument. After that you also will need to find the category by yourself in your method, after validation. Like this: "$category = Category::find($category_id); if (empty($category_id)) { return response()->json(['success' => false, 'message' => "Category not found!"], 404); }"

Comment: Where do you enter the ID?

Comment: sorry for deleting my comment  , i though it solved but it didn't. my question is when i remove `Category $category` from update() parameters , then laravel doesn't know $category in $category->title=$data['title']

Comment: I don't get what you mean? in postman?

Answer (score 1):

i fixed it

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {

        $category_faild = Category::find($id);
        if(is_null($category_faild)){
            return response()->json('دسته بندی مورد نظر یافت نشد' , 404);
        }

        $data = $request->all();

        $validator = Validator::make($data, [
            'title' => 'required|max:100|unique:categories',
            'description' => 'required|max:500',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json(['error' => $validator->errors(), 'Validation Error']);
        }

        $category = Category::find($id);
        $category->title = $data['title'];
        $category->description = $data['description'];
        $category->save();

        return response()->json([
            "success" => true,
            "message" => "با موفقیت ویرایش گردید",
            "data" => $category
            ]);

    }
```